# when the horizontal submenu goes beyond the edge of parent menu it should stick to the edge instead

Tags: html, css

html section ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

<ul class="main">
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">one</a></li>
<li class="parent">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)">two</a>
    <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">sub one</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">sub two</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">sub three</a></li>
    </ul> 
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">three</a>
    <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">sub one</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">sub two</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">sub three</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>

<li><a href="javascript:void(0)">four</a>
    <ul class="sub">
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">sub one</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">sub two</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">sub three</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

style section ---------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
<style>

ul, li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
.main > li {
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    padding:1px;
}
.main > li > a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px 20px;
}
.sub {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    width:300px;
    margin-left:-1px;
    margin-top: -1px;
}
.sub li {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-left:0;
    border-right:0;
}
.sub li:first-child {
    border-left:1px solid #000;
}
.sub li:last-child {
    border-right:1px solid #000;
}
.sub a {
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
}
.main > li:hover .sub {
    display:block !important;
}
.main > li:hover {
    padding:0;
    border:1px solid #000;
}
.parent:hover {
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff !important;
}
.parent a {
    border-bottom:1px solid #fff !important;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}

</style>

</body>
</html>
```

end of code ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
http://jsfiddle.net/SLDmd/
Description image,left in first comment

Comment: link to picture that describes a problem:
http://i44.tinypic.com/2rwn901.jpg

Comment: so,may one help  to solve this  by using js ?

Comment: For future questions, please find a shorter description of your problem for the title - it is overly long. Include the details in the actual post.

Answer (score 1):

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/85hFt/)

Add classes to the third and fourth's submenu:

```
<ul class="sub three">
<ul class="sub four">
```

Modify the `margin-left` for them accordingly:

```
.sub.three {
    margin-left:-141px;
}
.sub.four {
    margin-left:-147px;
}
```